Shift char* array to left
This is my code
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int i, j, k;
int arr_size = 5;
char* data[] = {"1234567", "1234576", "1234756", "1234765", "1234675"};
char temp[7];
char str[35];

void main() {
    for (i = 0; i < arr_size; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < arr_size; j++)
            strcat(str, data[j]);
        strcpy(temp, data[0]);
        for (k = 0; k < arr_size - 1; k++)
            strcpy(data[k], data[k + 1]);
        strcpy(data[arr_size-1], temp);

    }
}

First cycle is good, but on next cycle error: Segmentation fault!
Whats wrong ?
I need it to work "1234576", "1234756", "1234765", "1234675", "1234567"

Seems like a simple buffer overflow. Run this code in a debugger, it should be trivial to find out where the error is. If you don't know how, try to locate a video tutorial for the IDE you're using.

Two things: 1) A seven-character string needs space for eight characters to fit the null-terminator, if you have less storage you will go out of bounds and have undefined behavior; And 2) You can't modify literal strings like "1234567", and attempting to do so will lead to undefined behavior (which is why you should always use const char * for such strings).

And regarding buffer overflow, you will go way way out of bounds of str. You will append the strings in data 25 times to str. 25 times 7 is quite a bit more than 35.

I'm writing without the IDE from Midnight Commander

You have an array with pointers to strings. Instead of copying the strings, you could just shift the pointers in your array.
